# How to display Password as asterisk for Attributes

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have an attribute which requires user to enter their password. I have create such attribute as Text control type, but how can I have it display as asterisk instead of plain text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[PXDBCryptString](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=61059393-8873-451f-b474-783906330fc6) attribute on Data Access Class field should help

Comment: I think Krunal is trying to get it to work using the out of the box attributes. To my knowledge there is no way without getting into non standard ways. The best approach might to create your own dac and use PXDBCrypString or in some way see if you can to a graph cache attached and make the value field PXDBCrytString but that will do that to all attribute values.